# How to get perfect match text using XPath selector?

Tags: xml, xpath

For example:

XML file:

```
<root>
    <dropdwon>
        <option>
            <udhav sarvaiya>
            <udhav sarvaiya v>
            <udhav>
        </option>
    </dropdown>
</root>
```

I just want to get this string/text in my dropdown: **udhav**

so, I have used this XPath:

```
//select[@id="dropdownid"]/option[contains(text(), "udhav")]
```

but It's giving me 3 outputs:

```
udhav sarvaiya
udhav sarvaiya v
udhav
```

I only need output **udhav**

**So, what is XPath for the only perfect matched text?**

Comment: And where's your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below Xpath:

`//select[@id="dropdownid"]/option[text()="udhav"]`